# How to dynamically change autoscaling instance names

Tags: openstack, autoscaling, openstack-heat

I have created a heat stack which autoscales depending on CPU use. Each time a new instance is created, it is given a random name.

Is there a way to set a specific name with a counter added to the end of it so that each time a new instance is created it increases by 1?

E.g. Myinstance1, Myinstance2, Myinstance3 ... MyinstanceX

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Openstack HEAT, stack resource names are manipulated with stack_name and suffixed with a short_id. That's why on every autoscaled up instance you could see the instance name as such. This is how the implementation done in overall HEAT project and it is not possible to define instance name suffixed with incremental number.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. Glad I've now learned it isn't possible! I was going mad!

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly, and if you are Object Oriented Programing:

you are looking for a design pattern called `Factory`, or more simply, create a `static` member that will increase in the `constructor`, and will be added to the name `member` of the `instance` created.

Comment: I should have made that clearer. I'm not using OOP unfortunately.

Comment: in this case, what language do you use? and what does it mean `instance` in this non-OOP language? can you give some code example where an instance is given a random name?

Comment: I'm using a heat template to spin up some openstack instances which then autoscale. The template for this is defined using the YAML syntax

Comment: i am sorry, but it seems i cannot help you in this case. i don't know the environment well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom names by going to your Auto Scaling Groups and Tags tab, and then adding a tag with the key of "Name" and the value of "MyInstance". Numbering does not make that much sense since your instances are going to be launched and terminated constantly.

Answer (score 0):

**Update at 21/09/2020 :**

Seems that creating an incremental number is impossible so far, but I found a workaround to achieve my goal, so post here hoping that could give you some ideas.

**Mindset:**
I tried to find something (which is number) that is created dynamically with the instance for scaling up, to me that is `OS::Neutron::Port`, so I append one part of IP address after a string to get a distinctive name for each instance.

**Solution:**
1.Create a port `OS::Neutron::Port`.
2.Get IP address using `get_attr`.
3.Split it with dot as delimiter using `str_split`.
4.Append one part of the address to the string using `str_replace`.

**Sample Code:**

lb_server.yaml

```yaml
resources:
  corey_port:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network: { get_param: network }
      fixed_ips:
        - subnet: { get_param: subnet }

  number:
    type: OS::Heat::Value
    properties:
      value:
        # 192.168.xxx.yyy => [192,168,xxx,yyy]
        str_split: ['.', { get_attr: [corey_port, fixed_ips, 0, ip_address] }]

  server:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name:
        str_replace:
          template: Corey-%last%
          params:
            #  0   1   2   3
            #[192,168,xxx,yyy]
            "last%": { get_attr: [number, value, 3] } 
      flavor: { get_param: flavor }
......
```

The outcome shoud be Corey-168, Corey-50, Corey-254, etc.